# multiple ManyToOne relations serializer

Tags: django, optimization, django-rest-framework

sorry my english is not good.

Get request `book_id(pk)`

How do I serialize ManyToOne fields using `BookSerializer` to retrieve something

```
class Book(TimeStampedModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=False)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,unique=True)
    ...
    
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'books'


class BookMember(TimeStampedModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=False)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'book_member'


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name=_('email'))
    ...

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user'


class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserDetailSerializer(read_only=True, many=True, required=False)
    owner = UserDetailSerializer(read_only=True, many=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = '__all__'
```

### I need to book retrieve

```
class BookViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    queryset = Book.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BookSerializer
    renderer_classes = [JSONRenderer]

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = get_object_or_404(self.queryset, many=True)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)
        return serializer.data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can span a [**`ManyToManyField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField) over you `BookMember` model:

```
from django.conf import settings

class Book(TimeStampedModel):
    # …
    owner = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING
    )
    members = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        through='BookMember'
    )
    # …
    
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'books'


class BookMember(TimeStampedModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING
    )
    book = models.ForeignKey(
        Book,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'book_member'
```

Then you can serialize with:

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserDetailSerializer(read_only=True, many=True, required=False)
    members = UserDetailSerializer(read_only=True, many=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = '__all__'
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: Usually it is better to work with a [**`OneToOneField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField)
> instead of a `ForeignKey` that has `unique=True`. A `OneToOneField` is a `ForeignKey` with `unique=True` and some small
> modifications: for example it uses by default the name of the model in lowercase as
> [**`related_name=…`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)
> and makes accessing the relation in reverse more convenient since that does not require a *manager* in between.

---

> **Note**: Specifying [**`null=False`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#null) is not necessary: fields are by default not NULLable.